# MFC: How to use C++ Global Object in C

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

I have an MFC application in which I have declared a Global Object say "obj" in a file called MiRec2PC.cpp now I want to use this object in a C file.

I have used an approach in which I include the header file in which the structure of that particular object is declared. I also use a keyword "extern" with that obj when I use it . but still the compiler is showing a link error:

```
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib "LIBCMT" conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
httpApplication.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_iRecordInst
Debug/MiRec2PC.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
Creating browse info file...

MiRec2PC.exe - 2 error(s), 12 warning(s)
```

Regards

Umair

Comment: Does C even support objects? Are .obj files compatible between C and C++? Do you use the same compiler for both? Isn't it easier to just wrap the C++ object in a (COM) DLL and then call the DLL from your C application? I feel you're trying to make things more complex than required.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I need to be a little more specific when I say object actually I am referring to a structure variable. As far as compiler is concerned I am using VC++ 6.0. And I don't want to use COM. And things are complex here :) .I would be obliged if you come up with either of approaches like some C variable that can be accessed from C++ or some C++ variable that can be accessed from C. Hope to hear from you soon.

Regards
Umair

Comment: Why do you need a C-file in your C++ project? Why you can't compile it with C++ compiler?

Comment: Actually all the Device drivers are written in C therefore I need that C file.

Comment: Do you want to use C code in C++ or C++ code in C? It makes a difference. (And I thought modern device drivers are written in C++, not C. C is almost obsolete, except for some special devices, since it doesn't support OO programming.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access classes from C++ in C without some sort of indirection and/or interface. If you really want to use it in C (Why?) then you will have to devise some kind of extern "C" interface to your object.

E.g. implement some cinterface.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// It does not have to be void* but at this point it is the easiest thing to use.
typedef void * ObjCType;
ObjCType obj_get_obj (void);
int obj_get_value(ObjCType);

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

And then in cinterface.cpp implement the C language interface delegating to the Obj's member functions.:

```
#include <obj.hpp>
#include <cinterface.h>

// This is defined somewhere else.
extern Obj obj;

ObjCType obj_get_obj ()
{
  return &obj;
}

int obj_get_value(ObjCType o)
{
  return static_cast<Obj*>(o)->get_value ();
}
```

And finally, use the C interface in your source.c:

```
#include <cinterface.h>

int main ()
{
  ObjCType o = obj_get_obj ();
  int x = obj_get_value (o);
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to repeat the linkage specification for the function definitions.

Comment: Could you tell me the other way round how to use C++ variable not objects in C files with out using header files !

Comment: Oh, and there is a cast missing: `return static_cast<Obj*>(o)->get_value();`.

Comment: @Umair: For fundamental types you can use just plain pointers that you pass through either using extern "C" declared function or extern "C" using pointer declaration, which usually means adding it to some header anyway.